# async/await - How am I misunderstanding lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, locking

I have a multi-threaded application (async/await) and need a lock a block of code. This seems simple, so there must be something I don't understand about lock.

```
private readonly object addToDictionary = new object();
private void SetupDictionary()
{
   lock (addToDictionary)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"LOCK --{System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}--");
      if (!_dictionary.Add.ContainsKey(_tenantCode))
      {
         Console.WriteLine($"start {System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
         _dictionary.Add(_myKey, GetAnohterDictionary());
         Console.WriteLine($"done {System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
      }
   }
   Console.WriteLine($"RELEASE --{System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}--");
}
```

Here is my output:

```
LOCK --5--
start 5
LOCK --10--
start 10
LOCK --4--
start 4
done 5
RELEASE --5--
RELEASE --14--
```

I lock thread 5, start the dictionary load on thread 5, then lock thread 10. **Thread 5 should still be locked and thread 10 should not be able to get to the WriteLine statement.**

Eventually, I print 'done' for thread 5 and then release thread 5 (by leaving the block). I never see 10 and 4 get released because they throw an expectation when they add a duplicate to the dictionary.

Comment: Your title talks about async/await but I can't see any async/await here

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: There is also an implementation for a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where you do not need to do own locks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are locking against exactly the same instance of `addToDictionary` every time / for all threads?

Comment: Ya you probably need to make addToDictionary static so there will only ever be one instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you are using to do the lock is an instance property and that's not the way to achieve what you want. Every instance of your class has it's own instance of `addToDictionary`, so lock won't be effective.

You may want to use static variable instead:

```
private static readonly object addToDictionary = new object();
```

Comment: Just as note - if the `_dictionary` is also an instance field, then it is ok for `addToDictionary` to be also the instance field.

Comment: This answer is making a big assumption. Until the OP provides full code we can't know if this is correct or not.